# Can I take my monopod in my carry-on lugagge?

Tags: travel, monopod

I am decided to buy a monopod. I wonder if I will be allowed to take it on a plane in a carry-on luggage? If there is a **high chance** for it, I would rather buy the one that folds into smaller item, preferably one made of carbon fibers.

Comment: Hi @tnorgd - What country?

Comment: My incomming airports will be: FRA, CDG, WAW, SEA, AMS, DUS

Comment: Once I was flying to watch total solar eclipse. On that plane at least 40 tripods were in the carry-on luggages. Most of them not even put into the small bags. I still don't understand how it was allowed.

Comment: related question on the new Travel.SE: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/545/176

Answer (score 2):

You *usually* can and they will *usually* let you.

Obviously it has to **fold within the carry-on specifications of the airlines and the security regulations** of your departure and transiting airports.

Note that it is best to **carry a printed version of the applicable regulations with you** to avoid the case where you can but the do NOT let you.

With certain combinations of departure airport, airlines and destination you may be subjected to a different set of regulation at some point before the gate. In such case you should check both regulations printed. *The only thing is that I have not found a reliable source which indicates the while regulations apply to which combination.*

Answer (score 1):

There are reports on forums of [dpreview](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/read.asp?forum=1021&message=14266047), [Fred Miranda](http://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/topic/862425), [photokb](http://www.photokb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/photo-digital-slr/9652/Tripod-monopod-as-carry-on-luggage) and [boards.ie](http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?p=56096454) from users claiming to have done it, most of them several times. On the other hand, [Overclockers Australia](http://forums.overclockers.com.au/showthread.php?t=453683) has several people telling negative experiences.

As long as you meet dimension and weight limitations and don't have spiked foot on the monopod, I see little reason why it should be considered a hazard. But similarly shaped pool cues are in listed as [forbidden to carry-on by TSA](http://www.tsa.gov/travelers/airtravel/prohibited/permitted-prohibited-items.shtm). No mention of tripods/monopods in that list, but there is a note that the list is not intended to be all-inclusive. And a security officer might classify it as a *tool longer than 7 inches*, which is forbidden to carry-on.

So, as a conclusion - you might end up with a security official who has had a bad day, but I'd consider this a slim chance. If you have check-in luggage, just put your monopod there to be sure; travelling light, you'll *probably* be okay carrying on too.

Answer (score 0):

I routinely pack my tripod in my carry on here in the US. I have once had a screener say it wasn't allowed. My answer was, "ok, I'll just go back out and put it in my car and then come through security again without it." He grunted "ok" and had someone else show me the way out of the secure area. (she apologized for it as we were going and stamped my boarding pass with a priority pass to skip the line.) I went to the next security checkpoint down the concourse and breezed right through.

Answer (score 0):

never had trouble post or pre 9/11, not even in countries like Russia and the UK where they're more paranoid than most of the US (though the TSA seems to have caught up, I've not been in the US since they were established and don't plan to go until after they've disappeared again).

Answer (score -2):

Not carbon, but definitely compact, the [Twig Pod](http://photojojo.com/store/awesomeness/twig-pod/) folds like a tent pole, and pokes into the ground to stand on its own.  This is a short pole, best suited for a compact camera, but for $28, it looks like it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Do you suggest security will happily let you take such spike on-board an airplane?